# Postgres SELECT Across Time Zones Specific Day

Tags: postgresql

I have a two tables (orders and regions) that when joined return

```
orders.date        | orders.regions.tz
--------------------------------------
2016-01-01 2:00:00 | PST
2016-01-01 2:00:00 | EST
2016-01-01 2:00:00 | EST
...
```

I can select my different times in the corresponding time zones using:

```
SELECT date::timestamp at time zone regions.tz 
FROM orders INNER JOIN regions ON orders.region_id = regions.id;
```

Now I'm trying to find a way to SELECT all orders on that are on a specific day. That is:

- Orders in the PST region between Jan 1, 2016 12:00 AM PST and Jan 2, 2016 12:00 AM PST.
- Orders in the EST region between Jan 1, 2016 12:00 AM EST and Jan 2, 2016 12:00 AM EST.
- ...

I'm guessing this is going to rely on some sort of use of `without timezone and time` but I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: dont understand your question. What type is date? what is your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to probably cast to `::date`:

```
SELECT orders.*
FROM orders INNER JOIN regions ON orders.region_id = regions.id
WHERE (scheduled::timestamp at time zone regions.tz)::date = '2016-1-1'::date;
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know if it is the most efficient way to do things, this could just be done with a bunch of OR satements.

```
SELECT date::timestamp at time zone regions.tz 
FROM orders INNER JOIN regions ON orders.region_id = regions.id
WHERE (date::timestamp BETWEEN startTime AND endTime AND regions.tz = 'PST')
OR (date::timestamp BETWEEN startTime AND endTime AND regions.tz = 'EST')
```

You'll of course have to figure out all the start and end times for each individual timezone.